# How can i use user define fucntion to set default value for domain class variable in grails

Tags: grails

Here Cycle is a domain class

```
class Cycle {
    int lenght = 42 
    String[] monitor = new String[length]
    static mapping = {
       monitor defaultValue:"defaultstrval(length)"
    }
    def defaultstrval(int length)
    {
       String[] defaultval =new String[length]

       for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
       {
          defaultval[i]=","
       }

       return defaultval    
    }
}
```

Is Domain class only accept sql function.I really need help with good example.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the mapping closure to call your function you can simply call the function from your variable assignment like so

```
String[] monitor = defaultstravel(length)
```

Comment: The method has to be static since it's called from a static `mapping` block.

Comment: If i use this String[] monitor =  defaultstrval(length)             it seems the method return garbage value.how can i resolve this  Burt .